# Reading from binary file is unsuccessful in C

Tags: c, project

I am using C programming language and am trying to read the first string of every line in a binary File .

Example of data in the binary file (I have written to a txt file in order to show you)

> Iliya                 Iliya                 Vaitzman              16.00 israel                1 0 1

I want to read to first Iliya in the line (or what ever the first word in the line will be).

I am trying the following code but it keeps returning NULL to the string variable I gave him

The following code:

```
FILE* ptrMyFile;
    char usernameRecieved[31];
    boolean isExist = FALSE;
    ptrMyFile = fopen(USERS_CRED_FILENAME, "a+b");
    if (ptrMyFile)
    {
        while (!feof(ptrMyFile) && !isExist)
        {
            fread(usernameRecieved, 1, 1, ptrMyFile);
            if (!strcmp(userName, usernameRecieved))
            {
                isExist = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("An error has encountered, Please try again\n");
    }
    return isExist;
```

I used typedef and #define to a boolean variable (0 is false, everything else is true (TRUE is true, FALSE is false))

usernameRecieved keeps getting NULL from the fread .

What should I do in order to solve this?

Comment: You are aware that you're only reading a single byte in the fread()?

Comment: What't the format of the binary file?  You can't just read a C string from a binary file with `freed()`, unless it `\0` terminated and you know the exact position and length.  `userName` is not defined.

Comment: Your file-reading logic is wrong. The `feof()` function returns nonzero only when you've _already tried to read past the end of the file_. This means that after you successfully read the last record in the file, `feof()` returns false, and you then perform another `fread()` and proceed to use the result. The return value of `fread()` is the number of objects that have been read, so the correct procedure is to always test the return value of `fread()`, and if the value is zero or otherwise "wrong", _then_ you check `feof()` and decide whether to exit the loop. (Also see `ferror()`.)

Comment: [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html), [`ferror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ferror.html), [`feof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/feof.html)

Comment: curious about this, you're opening the file for reading & writing (binary mode), initial position is EOF

Comment: [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) would probably do you well to review, as the two in tandem are made for what it appears you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
fread(usernameRecieved, 1, 1, ptrMyFile);
```

try this:

```
memset(usernameRecieved, 0, sizeof(usernameRecieved));
fread(usernameRecieved, sizeof(usernameRecieved)-1, 1, ptrMyFile);
```

As it is, you are reading at most only one byte from the file.

Comment: I still recieve the same

[img]http://ufu.co.il/files/ox3rzk25hr6rqk51o5j2.jpg[/img]

Comment: Does the file really contain data and exists?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation on fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/)

A couple things: you're setting the count field in fread to 1, so you'll only ever read 1 byte, at most (assuming you don't hit an EOF or other terminal marker).
It's likely that what you want is:

```
fread(usernameRecieved, 1, 31, ptrMyFile);
```

That way you'll copy into your whole char buffer. You'll then want to compare only up to whatever delimiter you're using (space, period, etc).

It's not clear what "usernameRecieved keeps getting NULL" means; usernameRecieved is on the stack (you aren't using malloc). Do you mean that nothing is being read? I highly suggest that you always check the return value from fread to see how much is read; this is helpful in debugging.

Comment: That isn't null, that's a whole bunch of 'M's... Does your input file have a bunch of Ms/is it well formed and existant?